# Crypt Incursion stack help

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So me and my mate are just looking for clarification about [Crypt Incursion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Incursion).

For example, I play [Crypt Incursion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Incursion), targeting my graveyard. In response he plays [Crypt Incursion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Incursion) and also wants to target my graveyard.

Which [Crypt Incursion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Incursion) goes first? And if his does go first, am I then able to respond and target his graveyard instead?

Answer (score 5):

When you cast a spell, it goes on the stack before it resolves and takes effect. While it is on the stack, both players can cast instants or activate abilities "in response" to the spell or ability on the stack, and these responses will go on TOP of the stack. Once both players say that they don't wish to do anything else, the spell or ability on the TOP of the stack resolves. This means that the second [Crypt Incursion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Incursion) will resolve first, so when the first one resolves, your graveyard will no longer have creatures.

You cannot change which graveyard you wish to target in response. You choose your targets as you cast the spell (as you put it on the stack), and you cannot change that choice later.

From the [Basic Rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/EN_Magic_Basic_Rulebook_20090710.pdf):

> The spell doesn’t resolve (have its effect) right away—it has
> to wait on the stack. Each player, including you, now gets
> a chance to cast an instant or activate an activated ability
> in response. If a player does, that instant or ability goes on
> the stack on top of what was already waiting there. When
> all players decline to do anything, the top spell or ability
> on the stack will resolve.

and

> You choose the targets for a spell when you cast it, and
> you choose targets for an activated ability when you
> activate it. If you can’t meet the targeting requirements,
> you can’t cast the spell or activate the activated ability.
> Once you choose targets, you can’t change your mind
> later.

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose targets when you cast the spell. You cast the spell first, so your spell is on the bottom of the stack. Then your friend casts his spell which goes on top.

You resolve the stack from top to bottom, so his spell resolves first and exiles all the creatures in your graveyard, gaining him life. Then your spell resolves and exiles all the zero creatures in your graveyard, gaining you zero life.

You could always play some other spells after his spell resolves, which might put some creatures into your graveyard. You can't just change the target of your spell once you have cast it though, unless another card lets you.